# Problemas al restar fechas con carbon

Tags: mysql, laravel

El problema que tengo es que quiero obtener cuantos dias de vacaciones tiene un empleado el primer año se le dan 15 el segundo 30 y el cuarto 40 y asi sucesivamente en mi base de datos guardo la fecha que el ingreso el solicita vacaciones y quiero crear una funcion la cual me devuelva los dias que le quedan pendientes por cada año y si se pasa de esos dias que me de un valor negativo

esta es la funcion que estoy creando pero no se como puedo realizarlo de esta manera me da error por que quiero restar el año actual con el año que guardo en mi base de datos de antemano gracias por alguna sugerencia o ayuda

```
public static function dias_pendientes($id){


        $vigencia=\DB::table('empleado')
            ->select('empleado.vigencia')
            ->where('empleado.id', '=', $id)->get();


        $dia_actual=Carbon::now()->age;


        $menos_anos=$vigencia-$dia_actual;


        return $menos_anos;
```

lo realice de esta forma

```
 public static function dias_pendientes($id){


        $fecha_actual= Carbon::now();

        $vigencia = Empleado::select('vigencia')->where('id', $id)->first()->vigencia;

        $fechaVigencia = Carbon::parse($vigencia);

        $diferencia = $fechaVigencia->diffInYears($fecha_actual);





        return $diferencia;



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero de todo, estas mezclando días, años, fechas, números, modelos, arrays... en resumen un buen cacao.

Carbon::now()->age te da la edad (age) de alguien que nazca ahora (now()) no los días.

Lo primero que debes hacer es indicarle a eloquent que ese atributo es una fecha para que lo parsee a carbon solo. Esto se hace añadiéndolo al array date de tu modelo:

```
protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
        'fecha',
    ];
```

Después en tu consulta usas get(), pero si solo quieres una instancia deberías usar first() y como consejo, aunque no es obligatorio, deberías usar el modelo en lugar del usar "table"

```
$vigencia = Empleado::find($id)->vigencia;
```

o

```
$vigencia = Empleado::select('vigencia')->where('id', $id)->first()->vigencia;
```

Suponiendo que este campo sea la fecha de ingreso del empleado, sacar la "edad" o "antiguedad", ahora si que es con age:

```
$vigencia->age;
```

o

```
$vigencia->diffInYears(now())
```

o si tu verion de laravel es anterior a 5.6 y no tiene now()

```
$vigencia->diffInYears(Carbon::now())
```

Comment: si me funciona correctamente

Comment: ahora lo que tengo que hacer es si el mes del año actual es menor al mes del año de vigencia entonces que me reste un año al año actual

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de esta forma, espero que te sirva.

```
$fechaActual = Carbon::now();
// siendo $vigencia la fecha que traes de la tabla
$fechaVigencia = Carbon::parse($vigencia);

$diferencia = $fechaVigencia->diffInYears($fechaActual);
```

Comment: ->age es un Helper que se traduce a ->diffInYears(Carbon::now())